# How to call other classes object in new class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have creeated these three classes Tether, Mass and Spring. Now in the main() Class i want to combine all of these together to simulate the harmonic oscillator created by them but i am not sure wether and how i have to impliment the other classes' Variables in the main like the self.tx and self.ty of the Tether() Class or the self.x, self.y etc. from Mass() and so on since the should initiate the coupled Spring Mass System at the beginning, so that i can add the start velocity afterwards to start the simulation.

The Functions at the beginning are only for gettign the user Input, i impliment them here as well so that you could try the code if you need to.

```
def Grid():
global grid
grid = np.zeros((2,1))
return grid

def Quantity():
try:
    global quantity
    quantity = int(input('How many masses do you want to simulate?') )
    #grid = np.delete(grid1,0,1)

except:
    print('You must insert integers only!')
    Quantity()
return quantity


def Tether_properties():
global tether
tether = []
try:
    global x,y
    x = int(input('Where do you want to place your x coordinate of the tether?'))
    y =int(input('Where do you want to place your y coordinate of the tether?'))
    t = Tether(x,y)
    tether.append(t)
    #tether.append(t)
except ValueError:
    print('You must insert integers only!')
    Tether_properties()

def Mass_properties():
global masses
masses = []
for i in range(quantity):
    try:
        global x, y, vx, vy, w
        x = int(input('Where do you want to place your x coordinate of your mass?' ))
        y = int(input('Where do you want to place your y coordinate of your mass?'))
        vx = int(input('How fast do you want your Mass to move in direction of x?' ))
        vy = int(input('How fast do you want your Mass to move in direction of y?'))
        weight = int(input('How much do you want the Mass to weigh?'))
        if weight == 0:
            print('Mass must be an integer > 0 for the Mass!')
            Mass_properties
        else: 
            w = weight
        global m
        m  = Mass(x,y,vx,vy,w)
        masses.append(m)
    except ValueError:
        print('You must insert integers only!')
        Mass_properties()


def Spring_properties():  
global lx,ly,length,stiffness, spring_props
spring_props = []
for i in range(quantity):
    if i == 0:
        lx = tether[0].x_t_coord - masses[0].x_coord
        ly = tether[0].y_t_coord - masses[0].y_coord
        vector = np.array([[lx],[ly]])
        length = nl.norm(vector)
        try:
            stiffness = int(input('What stiffness do you want your spring to have? '))
        except ValueError:
            print('You must insert integers only for the stiffnes!')
            Spring_properties()
    else:
        lx = masses[i-1].x_coord - masses[i].x_coord
        ly = masses[i-1].y_coord - masses[i].y_coord
        vector = np.array([[lx],[ly]])
        length = nl.norm(vector)
        try:
            stiffness = int(input('What stiffness do you want your spring to have? '))
        except ValueError:
            print('You must insert integers only for the stiffnes!')
            Spring_properties()
    l = Spring(lx,ly,length,stiffness)
    spring_props.append(l)









class Tether():

def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.tx = x
    self.ty = y

@property
def x_t_coord(self):
    return self.tx

@property
def y_t_coord(self):
    return self.ty
```

class Mass():

```
def __init__(self,x,y,vx,vy,w):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    self.w = w

@property
def x_coord(self):
    return self.x

@property
def y_coord(self):
    return self.y

@property
def x_velo(self):
    return self.vx

@property
def y_velo(self):
    return self.vy

@property
def mass(self):
    return self.w
```

class Spring():

```
def __init__(self,lx,ly,length,stiffness):
    self.lx = lx
    self.ly = ly
    self.length = length
    self.stiffness = stiffness

@property
def lx_coord(self):
    return self.lx

@property
def ly_coord(self):
    return self.ly

@property
def length_value(self):
    return self.length

@property
def stiffness_value(self):
    return self.stiffness


class main():

def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question and in any case you should really try to boil things like that down to the smallest possible example that demonstrates your question, possibly going more abstract than your specific problem if it's a question about syntax or commonly used patterns - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. What do you mean by "implement the other classes' Variables in the main"?

Comment: As i did in the other classes like tether, in the init function i had to pass the x and y coordinates from the function Tether_properties so that i have an initial state in which the tether stands in the coordinates i get out of the function. If a want an initial state where mass 1 hangs on the tether and mass two hangs on mass 1 and so on i think i have to pass the coordinates, velocities etc i defined in the classes to the init of the Main class. But i don't know how i would do this.

Comment: You mean accessing those global lists (`masses`, `tether`, etc.) from `main`? You already do something like that in `Spring_properties` where you iterate over quantities, masses and tethers - that would work in `main`, too. But I most likely still don't get the question.